# Why doesn't margin-left/right apply to both buttons when they are next to each other?

Tags: html, css

```css
.button-box button {
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-box">
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Note that, the button-box div is part of a larger container that has both buttons centralized in the middle of the page.

Now, using margin-right for example, only the left button (send) moves left, while the right button next to it (reset) doesn't move. At first, i thought that's because the code first applies to the first button, and since the margin adds space between the button and the next element, which is the next button, the margin-right is then added between the first button and the second one, and the second one doesn't move because when the margin is added between it and the rest of the right space, there is no space leftwards to move, because the left button hasn't moved yet.

But that doesn't seem to explain why is it that if i add a big margin to the right or left, and then add just a little bit more, there is space for the second button to move too, but it doesn't. I don't understand why?

Comment: Here are not enough information to offer an answer. I can only suppose that somewhere you have defined last-child on button-box.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that illustrates the issue you're having. The code you posted exhibits no issues.

Comment: On the snippet you can see that only the send button is moved left, while the reset button stays on one place and doesn't move.

Comment: The centering is critical to the explanation here, but your snippet doesn't include it.

Comment: Because i didn't add it, but i said in my explanation that there is a container that centers the two buttons in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It does apply the right margin on the button unless you specify not to apply it. Just to show it better, added the inline-block div in the middle with the border.

https://jsfiddle.net/saravananchandru/es6rbpfu/2/

```
<div class="button-box">
    <div class="button-box-inner">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>  
    </div>
</div>

.button-box {
  text-align: center;
}

.button-box-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.button-box button {
    margin-right:50px;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

Comment: Even in your example, only the "send" button moves leftward, while the "reset" button doesn't move despite the margin-right.

Comment: Just for your reference, I had added one more button-box section to show the difference.
https://jsfiddle.net/saravananchandru/es6rbpfu/5/

Comment: What difference are you trying to show me? The second button does not move. The margin-right doesn't apply to it. That is my question.

Comment: Interesting! I could able to see that the margin-right has been applied. Not sure whether we both are talking the same thing. Anyhow, the first section is having the right side space before the border which is nothing but the margin-right. You can see more on by checking the browser inspect elements.

Comment: The second button has not moved despite having the margin-right applied to it. WHY is my question.

Comment: Maybe can you share the screenshot with your expectation? The fiddle should show the difference between the margin applied in the first row compared to the 2nd row. If you're still feeling that it's not moved, probably we both are talking two different things. Maybe any picture with the expectation of how it needs to look like and what you're getting as the output helps to understand it better.